# How to make a new index (ContentPage in my CarouselPage) for each label you gather from the db?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

this is my code. I want to achieve so I make a new carouselpage for each label I gather from the db. So I have made a for int and I get the values out from the label but now when I want to take it a step further and make a carouselpage for each label I am not sure how to make it work.

My page is a carouselpage both in code and xaml: so

```
public partial class PicturePage : CarouselPage
```

and in xaml:

```
<CarouselPage> &&   </CarouselPage>
```

My code:

```
List<string> labelList = new List<string> ();

async   void loadtest ()
    {
        var getItems = await parseAPI.getInformation ();
        foreach (var items in getItems ["results"])
        {
            var value = "";
            imagesList.Add (value = items ["label"].ToString());
        }

        base.OnCurrentPageChanged ();
        var index = Children.IndexOf (CurrentPage);


        for (int i = 0; i < labelList.Count; i++ && i < index; i++ ) { //how should I add a new index for each label I gather?

            myLabel.Text = myLabel.Text + labelList [i]+ "\n";

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them by setting the `Children` property and creating `ContentPages` on the fly at runtime:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imagesList.Count; i++){
    var carouselChild = new ContentPage {
            Padding = padding,
            Content = new StackLayout {
                Children = {
                    new Label {
                        Text = labelList[i],
                        FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize (NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)),
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                    }, 
                    new Image { Source = imagesList[i] }
                }
            }
    };

    Children.Add (carouselChild);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I am more comfortable with XAML but i will try this function out! Thanks